# How to reboot a windows phone if it is in an unresponsive state and the power button isn't working a well?

Tags: battery

My Windows phone isn't working well. The power button is dead and it has got stuck on some weird symbol having settings sign and battery sign.

Comment: Sure it's not just the low battery power screen?  The one that happens if you try to boot up with a dead battery.

Comment: Please clarify which phone you have.